# Sharepoint discussion board w/ attachments expiration policy

Tags: sharepoint

I want to set a retention policy (DB Settings -> Information Management Policy Settings) on a discussion board, but does the attachment get deleted as well?

Also, I have a discussion board retention policy right now that isn't working properly. The criteria is:

```
Last Updated + 30 days

Delete
```

There are plenty of dicussion items that are long past "Last Updated". Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known (but not very well documented) issue that discussion board items do not expire properly when setup with an Information Management Expiration policy. The usual symptom is that replies to a post expire, but the root post never will.

The workaround is to setup a [Disposition Approval workflow](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101544291033.aspx) and have that delete the items.

To answer the main part of your question - yes, when the item expires, the attachment should also expire.

Comment: if I create this workflow with SPDesigner, will the "Delete List Item" find and delete the attachment that is linked to the list item?

Comment: @Mike, yes that should delete the attachment.

Comment: I don't get it. I used this workflow correctly, and the discussion deleted properly, but the attachment is still there. Alot of the attachments that are redundant are still in the attachments folder shown on SPDesigner. Is there a tool to clean these up? Why are the attachments still there? I deleted them from both recycle bins...

Comment: I found that http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975002/en-us was not installed on my server and one of the hotfixes is that the attachments will delete correctly after its associated list has been deleted. 

Thanks!

Comment: @Mike - weird, it works for me without that hotfix installed.